# How to delete mulitple ids in mongdb but only 1 document per 1 id?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How to delete mulitple ids in mongdb but only 1 document per 1 id?
For example I have this collection:

```
{
    'id': 0
},
{
    'id': 0
},
{
    'id': 1
},
```

And I need to remove document with {id: {'$in': [0, 5]}}. But only 1 document for every id.
I want to get this result after my operation:

```
{
    'id': 0
}
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using a hybrid between Mongo Query Language and a programming language OS your choice to perform the deletion part.

The below example uses JavaScript and can be executed on Mongo Shell.

```
var resp = db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$id",
      "idToRemove": {
        "$first": "$_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "idsToRemove": {
        "$push": "$idToRemove"
      }
    }
  },
]).toArray()
db.collection.deleteMany({"_id": {"$in": resp[0]["idsToRemove"]}})
```

Answer (score 1):

[Bulk write](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/#bulk-write-operations) would be a way to do that, with a separate `deleteOne` operation for each `_id` value.